# 'Next' and 'Prev' icon missing in datepicker widget

Tags: jquery, datepicker, widget

I am trying to figure out jQueryUI. I am having some problem with the datepicker widget. In the demos in the jQuery website I am able to see the next and prev icons beside the month. In the jsp I wrote the spaces to the right and left are clickable to move to the next month or go to the one before, but the icons are missing. My code is below and and I am using the Redmond theme.  I am not sure why, hope someone can advise. I am placing the screenshots here as well. Thank you.

[image] [image]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title> 
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){       
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({               
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.jpg",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                showButtonPanel:true    
                });
        });     
       </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="Date">Date:</label>
            <label class="nofloat"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></label><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the web console, like an error trying to load the icon image file?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your response. I have found the solution, do scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the images folder of the theme to this folder: `css/`

The same where is the file `jquery-ui.css`

Comment: It doesen't seem to work when I place the images and the jquery-ui.css in the same folder. I have found a solution, do scroll down. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response, I think I have found the solution. The css and javascript files that are needed for jQueryUI should be placed together. They should not be placed together in a sub-folder, but directly under the WebContent folder(assuming you are using eclipse) at the same level as the jsp files.
[image]  [image]